# How to insert our Custom Java object id value into Database primary key in Java + Hibernate?

Tags: hibernate

I have one object which has one field in it that is unique now i want to insert this data into database but when i m trying to populate database object with the Java custom object then at the time of insert query it is saying
**Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'orphan_id', table '********'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.**

and this abc_id is not null.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "abcd")
public class Abcd{
    @Id
    private String abcId;

    private String abcGroup;

    private String abcState;

   }
```

Repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface AbcdRepository extends CrudRepository<Abcd, String> {

}
```

In Service class I am populating this DB object using builder pattern, but it is giving me below error:-

```
  AbcdRepository.save(abcd);
```

Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'abcd_id', table 'xxxxx'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

Please help me I m struggling alot to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

You need generate Id. For example,

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "abcd")
public class Abcd{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String abcId;

    private String abcGroup;

    private String abcState;

   }
```

Various GenerationType [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html)

Comment: But I don't want to add generation type, I want to set its value which is coming in the object itself.

Comment: Ok... Please show me how you set id

Comment: Suppose I want to save abcd object to DB so now from one object I am getting the value and using that value I am creating ABCD object e.g., 
abcd.builder.id(obj.getId()).build.

Like this so whenever I am calling abcdrepository.save(abcd) then it is giving error for Id.

Comment: Please attach code...